# How do I use Ajax to build a dropdown of custom fields based on a post selected in previous dropdown?

Tags: custom-field, ajax, dropdown

I'm inexperienced with ajax. I'm building a form that will allow the user to grab a custom post type from the first  field that will return the value of the post ID. Then, I'd like ajax to take that post ID and build a second dropdown based on some custom fields for that post.

Here's what I have so far, which was adapted from the first answer on this question: [Filter a second dropdown list when a value is chosen in the first one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177141/filter-a-second-dropdown-list-when-a-value-is-chosen-in-the-first-one)

In functions.php:

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_dynamic_dropdown', 'dynamic_dropdown_func' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_dynamic_dropdown', 'dynamic_dropdown_func' );
}
function dynamic_dropdown_func () {
    global $wpdb;
    if (isset($_POST['event'])) {
        $event_id = $_POST['event'];
        $first = get_field('first_day',$event_id);
        $last = get_field('last_day',$event_id);
        $event_dates = '<option value="" disabled selected>Choose Date</option>';
        $event_dates .= '<option value="'.$first.'">'.$first.'</option>';
        while($first<$last) :
            $first = $first + 1;
            $event_dates .= '<option value="'.$first.'">'.$first.'</option>';
        endwhile;
    }
ob_clean();
return $event_dates;
wp_die();
}
```

(I'm aware the code to build the dates still needs some work to display proper dates.)

And then, in the page template:

```
<?php function date_chooser () {
    $ajax_url = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );
    $grabDates = "
        <script>
            var ajaxUrl = '{$ajax_url}',
            dropdownEvent = jQuery('#chooseEvent'),
            dropdownDate  = jQuery('#chooseDate');
            dropdownEvent.on('change', function (e) {
                var value = e.target.selectedOptions[0].value,
                success,
                data;
                if (!!value) {
                    data = {
                        'event' : value,
                        'action' : 'dynamic_dropdown'
                    };
                    success = function ( response ) {
                        dropdownDate.html( response );
                    };
                    jQuery.post( ajaxUrl, data, success );
                }
            });
        </script>";
    return $grabDates;
}
echo date_chooser(); ?>
```

This code is getting me part of the way. Once the #chooseEvent dropdown has a selection, it is capture the proper post ID, and then the #chooseDate dropdown just empties itself from my placeholder  but never loads anything else.

I've tried just having the dynamic_dropdown_func() just return a "Hello world!" and it doesn't do that either, so somehow I think I'm not triggering and returning the ajax function properly.

Comment: in your JS you've got `if (!!value) { ` (i.e., double `!`).  Is that just a typo when you entered your question, or is that actually in your _real_ code?

Comment: @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron I think it's an intentional boolean coercion. I don't think it's necessary here, as (to the best of my knowledge) a `<option>`'s value is always a string, even when missing the `value` attribute and inner text - so `if(value)` *should* be sufficient. But the coercion won't hurt anything, and might catch some strange edge-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dynamic_dropdown_func()`, at the end try `echo $event_dates;` instead of `return $event_dates;`.

Also, I'm wondering why you declare `global $wpdb;` when you don't seem to use it?

Comment: Scott -- that did it. Thanks!

That global $wpdb was just leftover from the code I based it on above. Hadn't even occurred to me that I wouldn't need to to just use the get_field queries.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) over [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), as I seem to have more control over error processing.

In your page template, do the following:

```
function
date_chooser ()
{
    $ajax_url = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );
    $grabDates = "
    <script>
        var ajaxUrl = '{$ajax_url}',
        dropdownEvent = jQuery('#chooseEvent'),
        dropdownDate  = jQuery('#chooseDate');
        dropdownEvent.on('change', function (e) {
            var value = e.target.selectedOptions[0].value,
                success,
                data;
            if (!!value) {
                var data = {
                    action: 'dynamic_dropdown',
                    event: value
                    } ;

                jQuery.ajax ({
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: true,
                    url: ajaxUrl,
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function (response) {
                        // handle ajax success
                        if (response.success) {
                            // handle success, returned with wp_send_json_success ()
                            dropdownDate.html (response.data) ;
                            }
                        else {
                            // handle errors, returned with wp_send_json_error ()
                            }
                        },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        // handle ajax errors
                        }
                    }) ;
                }
            });
        </script>";
    echo $grabDates;
}
```

In your `functions.php`, do the following:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_dynamic_dropdown', array ($this, 'dynamic_dropdown_func' ));
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_dynamic_dropdown', array ($this, 'dynamic_dropdown_func' ));

function
dynamic_dropdown_func ()
{
    if (!isset($_POST['event'])) {
        wp_send_json_error ('event not set') ;
        }

    $event_id = $_POST['event'];
    $first = get_field('first_day',$event_id);
    $last = get_field('last_day',$event_id);
    $event_dates = '<option value="" disabled selected>Choose Date</option>';
    $event_dates .= '<option value="'.$first.'">'.$first.'</option>';
    while($first<$last) :
        $first = $first + 1;
        $event_dates .= '<option value="'.$first.'">'.$first.'</option>';
    endwhile;

    ob_clean () ;

    wp_send_json_success ($event_dates) ;
}
```

Note the use of [wp_send_json_success()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/) and [wp_send_json_error()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_error/)

Comment: Tried this one. It ended up not triggering any changes to the Choose Date fields at all -- not even wiping out what I previously had in there. The response above worked, however, so I'm good to go.